# Laravel 4 - Select related models

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have following table

```
Schema::create('jokes_categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('is_active');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('jokes', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('content', 200)->unique();;
    $table->enum('is_active', array('Y', 'N'));
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('jokes_categories');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**In the jokes table `category_id` is a foreign key and it has a one-to-many relationship with `jokes_categories`**

In the model I have the following:

```
class Joke extends \Eloquent {

    public static $rules = array();

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = array();

    public function JokesCategory(){
         return $this->belongsTo('JokesCategory');
    }
}
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
$jokes = Joke::all();
```

But it does not pull through `joke_categories`.`name` (I was under the impression that the model definition will directly help to pull related models)

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is just on the Joke table.

You could eagerload the categories ie.

```
$jokes = Joke::with('JokesCategory')->get();
```

See docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

The convention is actually camel case instead of pascal case, otherwise Laravel doesn't seem to automatically load the relationships. I made the same mistake and couldn't figure out why my relationships where not loading automatically.

```
public function jokesCategory()
```